# IDBcommand executenonquery. check for = 0 vs <1

Tags: .net

```
 using (IDbCommand dbCmd = TXController.CreateDbCommand(sSQlStmt))
 {
    int rowsAffected= dbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();    
 }

if(rowsAffected = 0)
or
if(rowsAffected <1)
   throw someException
```

which one is better?
context : sql command is an UPDATE.
Already refer to MSDN and following link. Not gonna use store procedure.
Any other case it will return -1?
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/spike/2009/01/27/sqlcommand-executenonquery-returns-1-when-doing-insert-update-delete/

Comment: Do you really think *this* will make or break your application in terms of overall performance/reliability?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever : unlikely, I am curious about other case when it return <0.Clearer understanding might help to distinguish cases.